# Eliminate the long polling of the external tasks in Camunda to the process engine

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm trying to eliminate the long polling method of the camunda process engine to notify the external tasks client.

My first attempt is to use the ExecutionListener class and his method notify at the start event of an activity in my bpmn to send a message to a AWS SQS queue with the external task id at the payload.

After the sending of the message my External Task will pull the message from the queue, process it and send a response via another AWS SQS queue to the process engine with the external task id in the payload.

At the receiving of the response message from the queue my process engine will capture the external task id from payload and complete the external task activity. Another way would be my external task make a post request at the [external-task/{ext-task-id}/complete].

My question is if there is another best method in order to achieve the decoupling of the process engine and the external tasks and how can I programmatically capture the external task id.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic pattern you will need here is having the actual "external" task client running on the same machine as your engine.
It will regularly subscribe to tasks (using the internal API, not the long polling) and then trigger "the real" external worker via message send/receive before completing the task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Having the external task running on the same machine for systems with low TPS is not an issue. The problem is more related with the way that the external task are "notified" of new activities to be executed by the external task. In fact, following the standard pattern of camunda, the external pull activities from the engine. What I want is to send messages to my external tasks related to activities to be executed.